# mysql int field always returning the same value

Tags: mysql, primary-key

Recently MySQL 5.1.49  (OSX) started inserting the same value '2147483647' for ALL integer fields named `id` and set as primary key. This is happening for all databases and all tables. Here's the a quick example:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO packages(id,name,rate) VALUES ('37364428662',"Testing","300");
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM packages;
+------------+---------+------+
| id         | name    | rate |
+------------+---------+------+
| 2147483647 | Testing |  300 |
+------------+---------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I'm attempting to re-install MYSQL as nothing else seems to be working : / I'll post any solutions I manage but meanwhile any help is always appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because your `id` field is a 32 bit integer and the value 37364428662 will require more than 32 bits to store. Try changing the type of `id` to an unsigned int, or some larger integer type.

It appears when you try to enter 37364428662 it's defaulting to the largest possible value for an int 32 (2147483647).

Comment: Thanks Dirk! That was the solution. Must have forgotten my CS 101 lessons about the biggest int possible...

Comment: Don't worry. I never remember the actual value, I had to Google it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to insert a value for an id 37364428662 which is larger then the maximum allowed size of your integer field (2147483647).